# mingw32: cmake does not find boost on windows

Tags: windows, boost, cmake, mingw

I am writing a Linux program with Qt and boost, using cmake. Everything is fine there,
but now I want to port this program to windows. Having installed cmake from here
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.20.5/cmake-3.20.5-windows-x86_64.msi
and Qt by `qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.12.11.exe` (which is the offline installer with
all frills). The Qt installation also did install a mingw environment.
In my CMakeLists.txt, I search the boost libraries with

```
find_library(LIB_BOOST_FILESYSTEM "boost_filesystem")
find_library(LIB_BOOST_SYSTEM "boost_system")
find_library(LIB_BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS "boost_program_options")
```

Then I installed boost like described here: https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6
using the toolchain `gcc`

I deviated from the description in that I placed the directories like this:

1. Extracted boost source to `C:\Users\picard\boost_1_70_0`
2. Created a folder for Boost.Build installation: `C:\Users\picard\boost-build`
3. Created a folder within for building: `C:\Users\picard\boost_1_70_0\build`
4. Created a folder for installation: `C:\Users\picard\boost`

Boost build and installation itself ran fine. I set the environment variables to

```
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR    C:\Users\picard\boost\include\boost_1_70\
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR    C:\Users\picard\boost\lib\
BOOST_ROOT          C:\Users\picard\boost_1_70_0\boost
```

I also tested changing the `BOOST_ROOT` to other values like `C:\Users\picard\boost`
but I guess, I did not hit the correct one. The result is always the same:

```
CMake error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIB_BOOST_FILESYSTEM 
    linked by target "myprogram" in directory c:/Users/picard/myprogram
LIB_BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS
    linked by target "myprogram" in directory c:/Users/picard/myprogram
LIB_BOOST_SYSTEM
    linked by target "myprogram" in directory c:/Users/picard/myprogram
```

The cmake-skripts for boost are located (I checked this) in the boost installation
dir: `c:\Users\picard\boost\lib\cmake`

In the directory `c:\Users\picard\boost\lib` there are all the boost libraries I expect, following the name scheme:
`libboost_*-mgw73-mt-[d|]-x32-1_70.a`
I guess, the `mt` stands for multithreading, so I added

```
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
```

to my `CMakeLists.txt`, but it did not change anything.

I also followed advices from here:

[find_package() doesn't detect boost on Windows Cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969280/find-package-doesnt-detect-boost-on-windows-cmake)

[Compiling C++ with Boost 1.68.0 on Windows using CMake and MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364155/compiling-c-with-boost-1-68-0-on-windows-using-cmake-and-mingw)

[CMake cannot find Boost on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357626/cmake-cannot-find-boost-on-windows)

[CMake does not find Boost on Custom Location on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404625/cmake-does-not-find-boost-on-custom-location-on-windows)

The only one which gives me more output is `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON)`:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
    Boost_DEBUG
```

Maybe things changed recently, but I guess, I have set the wrong paths in my
environment variables.

Thanks for you answers!

Update against hints by Tsyvarev:
Changing the `find_library()` to `find_package()`, cmake tells me to set the policy CMP0074. I did so by adding `cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)` to my `CMakeLists.txt`
This is a step forward, now there is a new output:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt/Qt5.12.11/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Qt5.12.11/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found Boost 1.70.0 at C:/Users/picard/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem
-- Found boost_headers 1.70.0 at C:/Users/picard/boost/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.70.0
-- Found boost_filesystem 1.70.0 at C:/Users/picard/boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.70.0
-- No suitable boost_filesystem variant has been identified!
--   libboost_filesystem-mgw73-mt-d-x32-1_70.a (mgw73, detected mgw7, set Boost_COMPILER to override)
--   libboost_filesystem-mgw73-mt-x32-1_70.a (mgw73, detected mgw7, set Boost_COMPILER to override)
CMake Error at C:/Users/picard/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0/BoostConfig.cmake:95 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/Users/picard/boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.70.0/boost_filesystem-config.cmake

  but it set boost_filesystem_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_filesystem" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:
 
  No suitable build variant has been found.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/picard/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0/BoostConfig.cmake:124 (boost_find_dependency)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/picard/myprogram/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

The problem is now the compiler identification (mgw73 vs. mgw7) mismatch. Using `set(Boost_COMPILER "mgw73")`, the message stays the same, using `set(Boost_COMPILER "mgw7")`, the message changes to

```
--   libboost_filesystem-mgw73-mt-d-x32-1_70.a (mgw73, Boost_COMPILER=mgw7)
--   libboost_filesystem-mgw73-mt-x32-1_70.a (mgw73 Boost_COMPILER=mgw7)
```

I have only one MinGW (7.3) installed, and used this installed MinGW to build boost.

Comment: Variables like `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`, `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` affects only on [find_package(Boost)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html). These variables have no effect on plain `find_library` calls.

Comment: So ``find_library`` is not the way to go?

Comment: If you ask whether one can **able** find Boost libraries via `find_library`, then the answer is "yes, but [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) requires its own hints". If you ask whether `find_library` is the **good** way for find Boost libraries, then the answer is "no, `find_package(Boost)` is always preferable way".

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, but with mgw131 and mgw13:

**Boost_COMPILER mgw131**

-- No suitable boost_random variant has been identified!
--   libboost_random-mgw131-mt-d-x64-1_70.a (mgw131, detected mgw13, set
Boost_COMPILER to override)

**Boost_COMPILER -mgw131**

-- No suitable boost_random variant has been identified!
--   libboost_random-mgw131-mt-d-x64-1_70.a (mgw131, Boost_COMPILER=-mgw131)

**Boost_COMPILER -mgw13**

-- No suitable boost_random variant has been identified!
--   libboost_random-mgw131-mt-d-x64-1_70.a (mgw131, Boost_COMPILER=-mgw13)

**Boost_COMPILER mgw13**

-- No suitable boost_random variant has been identified!
--   libboost_random-mgw131-mt-d-x64-1_70.a (mgw131, Boost_COMPILER=mgw13)

Taking a look to cmake file, I saw this:

```
if(Boost_COMPILER AND NOT Boost_COMPILER STREQUAL "mgw131")
  _BOOST_SKIPPED("libboost_random-mgw131-mt-d-x64-1_70.a" "mgw131, Boost_COMPILER=${Boost_COMPILER}")
  return()
endif()

if(BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET AND NOT BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET STREQUAL "mgw131")
  _BOOST_SKIPPED("libboost_random-mgw131-mt-d-x64-1_70.a" "mgw131, detected ${BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET}, set Boost_COMPILER to override")
  return()
endif()
```

I solved the problem by setting "mgw13" value to Boost_COMPILER and BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET just before calling find_package and running updatelibboost_toolset.sh script:

```
# Find the package and import the target 
if(WIN32 OR MINGW)
    SET(Boost_DEBUG ON)
    # set Boost_COMPILER to mgw13, to avoid (mgw131, detected mgw13, set Boost_COMPILER to override) error with boost_random
    message(STATUS "[build_cots.cmake]: set 'mgw13' value to Boost_COMPILER and BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET for Windows")
    set(Boost_COMPILER "mgw13")
    set(BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET "mgw13")
    # change cmake mgw version from mgw131 to mgw13 to make it work
    execute_process(COMMAND bash ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cots/updatelibboost_toolset.sh
                WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR}/Boost/lib/cmake"
                COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT 
                COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY)
endif()
message(STATUS "[build_cots.cmake]: Boost_COMPILER ${Boost_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "[build_cots.cmake]: BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET ${BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET}")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS math random system thread filesystem chrono atomic regex date_time PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProject/Install/Boost")
```

updatelibboost_toolset.sh script replace "mgw131 by "mgw13 because, even if you change the value of BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET, it will recover "mgw13" value.
This script make replacement in all files that includes "*mgw131*" on their name:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Running updatelibboost_random.sh
# Recursively search for files that contain "mgw131" in the name
find . -type f -name "*mgw131*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file
do
  sed -i 's/"mgw131/"mgw13/g' "$file"
done
```

And know it's working fine